# Can't find images paths from a local data array

Tags: javascript

## Summary

Hey there! i’m working on a small project about a restaurant menu app which so i’m building this in vanilla JS using webpack as bundler.

### Issue

the problem that i have is that when i’m using the data from a local array in my project can’t find the images path and i really don’t know why is happen this.
project structure

[image]

How i’m using the data from the array:

```js
import menu from '../data/data';

const Main = () => {
  const view = `
    <div class="menu-items">
      ${menu.map(menuItem => `
        <article class="menu-item">
          <img src=${menuItem.img} alt=${menuItem.title} class="photo" />
          <div class="item-info">
            <header>
              <h4>${menuItem.title}</h4>
              <h4 class="price">$${menuItem.price}</h4>
            </header>
            <p class="item-text">
              ${menuItem.desc}
            </p>
          </div>
        </article>
      `).join('')}
    </div>
  `;
  return view;
};

export default Main;
```

### The error message appearing in my console:

[image]

My hunches are: maybe could be that i need an image webpack loader but also i think that is a problem with how i'm using or writing the images path, so if someone knows how i can solve this, pleas i hope you can help me.

Also here i left the project repo if is necessary for someone:
https://github.com/armandopbringas/menu-app

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the problem. Do you host the images/ directory you are trying to fetch ?

Comment: I see your images folder in your src, but with the way you wrote the urls it should be hosted at the root of the project (in the public/ folder if the server entrypoint is in public/)

Answer (score 0):

I gave a quick look into your project on GIT. It seems like the "public" directory is the one that should contain the images.

That's the default directory that the server is getting the files.

Right now the images directory is on "src" directory.

When the browser requests an image on "http://localhost:8080/images/item-1.jpg" the server will look for it on "your-root-dir/public/images/item-1.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Just put yout image folder in 'public' directory, as suggested above, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the images folder to the public folder.
2. Change the img link in the data menu array - /images/item-1.jpeg

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is move all your images to public directory and leave the image path (that you have given in `data.js` as it is).
Or you can even remove the leading `.` from image path and make it as `/images/....`

Once in public directory, images will be picked up from there.

[image: Screenshot]